# Can we deforest nqueens program using short cut deforestation?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to see if the nqueens program can be deforested using short cut deforestation, 
The code i am using is,

```
n = 8  
nqueens 0 = [[]]  
nqueens k = [p:q | p <- [1..n], q <- nqueens (k-1), safe p q k]
```

and safe is defined as usual.

I tried getting to see the output of GHC by enabling optimizations but it was too difficult to understand.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to just look at core. There are other intermediate forms that may be more useful. From the docs:

> Use the debug flag -ddump-simpl-stats to see what rules fired. If you need more information, then -ddump-rule-firings shows you each individual rule firing and -ddump-rule-rewrites also shows what the code looks like before and after the rewrite

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out. I guess the ddump-rule-rewrites was not present in the version i was using.